# Getting only last notification on iOS via firebase if not connected to internet

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

The issue is that I want to send push notifications to iOS and I am able to do it via the `token` to the specific device and everything is working fine but the issue I am facing is that **I only get one one notification if my phone is not connected to internet, when I connect it back to the internet.**

Like If I send 5 different notifications to a token via `POST Request` using `Postman` and I had turned off my `Mobile phone Data` and my `Wifi` and after sometime I turn on any one of them then I only receive the last notification which I request out of the 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about 'non-collapsible' messages in the Firebase documentation if you expect to get all messages.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=1 clearly states

> Except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible by default.

Comment: I tried so many things today but facing the same issue.
I made function via which any number of notifications can be fired by a post request and every time it adds something unique to the JSON by adding a random number I am pasting the JSON structure in the next comment please have a look. pasting it there because it will exceed the word limit.

Comment: `
let rId = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3901))
let notificationJson = [
"notification":[
"body" : "\(iteration) - This week's edition.",
 "title" : "\(iteration) - NewsMag.com",
            ],
            "data" : [
                "volume" : "3.21.15",
                "contents" : "",
                "message" : "s\(rId)"
            ],
            "apns":[
                "headers":[
                    "apns-priority":"10",
                    "apns-collapse-id": rId
                ]
            ],
            "to" : "my_Token"
            ] as [String : Any]
`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting of the JSON cannot add formatting in comments, That's why I stripped it to the minimum text possible.

Comment: So, what did you learn from the link I gave you and then, how did you change what you are trying to do from what you learned?  It seems to me your comments above are only saying (basically) "I'm doing the same thing and getting the same result" - one definition of insanity (which does come from programming sometimes, though that is a different story... :)  The link (and quote) from firebase pretty clearly (though a bit 'backward' statement) states that you will only get the LAST notification when you come back online - so your results are consistent with the documentation.

Comment: @user3745635 - here is a nice article that I think shows what you are trying to do overall - get latest NewsMag info to your app users' - https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started  Note that push notifications are NOT 'for' the news, they are to report that there IS news.  You should get the user to open your app to see the latest X things.  Hope all this helps (and, if so, please consider marking the answer as correct - I'm trying to get my 'score' up! ;)

Comment: I had gone through everything there the main thing was that you can add apns-collapse-id different for every notification so none of them gets collide so I added a random number there but it's not solving the problem.

Comment: You keep saying "problem" as if it were something not working as advertised/documented.....  I have said (and documented for you) several times that YOU ARE SEEING THE EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR.  The 'problem' is in how you are trying to approach this - you need to consider your expected result (see my previous comment) and use the tools that are provided instead of trying to 'fix' what is documented (and working) in a particular way.  I really can't help you 'fix' what isn't broken, so I hope you take these comments and learn what you CAN do - you will have happier users, too....

Comment: @CFPSupport thank you for comments and link.. its stated by given link that only last message can be received.  Could you please help us what we have to do if we want to receive all the custom server notifications like whtsapp or other apps..

Comment: @ManivelGopi (and others...) - you should be looking at firebase as it is documented - you will only get the last notification.....  Once you understand that, then if you "want to receive all the custom server notifications", you either 1) don't use firebase (as they only send as a notification) or 2) use a different method to get all the 'other' messages (like polling your server for missed items) or 3) Look at other services, (like PubNub.com) - that serve more 'chat' applications than just 'notification' (which is, again, all that firebase does).

Comment: can someone help iam not getting even single notification from firebase when device comes online from offline...if device is online only getting messages

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're sending collapsible messages. And the FCM documentation states that:

> If the device is connected but in Doze, a low priority message is
>   stored by FCM until the device is out of Doze. And that's where the
>   collapse_key flag plays a role: **if there is already a message with the
>   same collapse key (and registration token) stored and waiting for
>   delivery, the old message is discarded and the new message takes its
>   place (that is, the old message is collapsed by the new one).** However,
>   if the collapse key is not set, both the new and old messages are
>   stored for future delivery.

You can try sending non-collapsible messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to clarify a situation that, in essence, isn't an issue but rather depends on how iOS/Android and Firebase opt to handle notifications.

There are two categories of notifications:

Notifications that include both the JSON notification key and data.
Notifications that solely consist of the given data key without the notification key.

According to Google's documentation, notifications with the notification key are categorized as "always collapsible"https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options. This implies that when notifications are dispatched, a collapse_key with the value "com.organization.myapp" is automatically appended to the notification's JSON.

Even if one attempts to modify this value by changing the "collapse_key" key to a random, ever-changing value, the Firebase SDK will persistently replace it with "com.organization.myapp" when transmitting the notification.

Consequently, the behavior we find problematic arises: if we close our smartphone's internet and send five notifications, only the last one is received when a connection opens. This occurs because the collapse_key remains constant, causing FCM to overwrite notifications with the same key and deliver only the most recent one to the user.

Conversely, if we transmit a notification without the notification key, solely employing the data key, it will lack a "collapse_key," and as a result, all notifications will be delivered without any issues.

It is important to note that notifications lacking the notification key are not conveyed to the user in the same manner as those that include it. Therefore, a customized approach must be developed to ensure that the notification popup appears on the user's smartphone.